# Ruby method arguments

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I need to check the third parameter of a method:

```
def NFS(configsHash, optionsHash, backupType)
```

I want to use an `if` statement to check the path where `backupType` is to be saved. Something like:

```
If #{backupType} == "dir/file/path/name/time"
   STDOUT.puts("Backup will be saved to current folder.")
else 
   STDOUT.puts("Putting into backup folder")
   STDOUT.puts(mkdir #{backups})
```

But I haven't been able to get the syntax right. Any suggestions?

Comment: we can't know what backupType object is, so can't give a good answer for you. Also, in ruby, as a strong convention, you should use method names in lower case, and use underlines for variable names instead of camel case.

Comment: backupType is a string. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: For `mkdir` operations, you probably want to use [FileUtils](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html) rather than smashing around in the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if backupType == "dir/file/path/name/time"
   puts "Backup will be saved to current folder."
else 
   puts "Putting into backup folder"
   Dir.mkdir "path/goes/here"
end
```

Notice that STDOUT has been dropped off.  That is redundant.  If you do STDOUT.puts.object_id and puts.object_id you will see they refer to the same things.  Also, notice that it is Dir.mkdir; not just mkdir; it needs to be called on the Dir class.

Modified to be a little more idiomatic.  I also dropped the puts from in from of the Dir.mkdir; as I assume that is not really what you intended.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You are correct in your assumption

Answer (score 2):

You can also go with this:

```
case backupType
when "dir/file/path/name/time"
  puts("Backup will be saved to current folder.")
else
  puts("Putting into backup folder")
  puts(Dir.mkdir backups)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Assuming that backupType is a string 
if backupType == "dir/file/path/name/time"
   print "Backup will be saved to current folder."
else 
   print "Putting into backup folder"
   # This part below is tricky since I don't know what the backups variable is referring to
   print Dir.mkdir backups
end
```

@fotanus in the comments makes great suggestions on naming conventions, but to ensure consistency I've kept the names the same for the answer.

Comment: Yes, backupType is a string.